# Error in Mailbox Migration from Gsuite to Office 365

Tags: google-api, migration, office365, google-calendar-api

Getting below error while migrating mailbox from Gsuite to office 365;

```
Error: GooglePermanentWebException/WebException: Error: The API call to Google ended in the error: uri=https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/users/me/calendarList?maxResults=250 response={ "error": { "errors": [ { "domain": "calendar", "reason": "notACalendarUser", "message": "The user must be signed up for Google Calendar." } ], "code": 403, "message": "The user must be signed up for Google Calendar." } } . --> The remote server returned an error: ‎(403)‎ Forbidden.
```

Comment: I have given the below scopes;
https://mail.google.com/
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar
https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.settings.sharing

Comment: welcome to stack please edit your question include [example]